# Laravel Models & Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, models, relationships

I try to build a relationship between a user and a bond. One bond contains always two users (debtor, creditor).

At the end I want to get a user model if I call `$bond->debtor` or `$bond->creditor`

User Model:

```
public function bonds()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bond::class);
}
```

Bond Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['description', 'amount', 'debtor_id', 'creditor_id'];

public function debtor()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'bond_user', 'debtor_id', 'user_id');
}

public function creditor()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'bond_user', 'creditor_id', 'user_id');
}
```

And two migrations:

```
Schema::create('bonds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->float('amount', 8, 2);
        $table->integer('debtor_id');
        $table->integer('creditor_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('bond_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('debtor_id');
        $table->integer('creditor_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Whenever I call eg. `$bond->debtor` I get an integer instead of the user model.

---

**UPDATE**

I find the solution:

User Model:

```
public function bond_debtor()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bond::class, 'debtor_id');
}

public function bond_creditor()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bond::class, 'creditor_id');
}
```

Bond Model:

```
public function debtor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'debtor_id');
}

public function creditor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creditor_id');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried $bond->debtor() instead of $bond->debtor got a feeling they yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

When setting relationships, you need

1. Set the field type of the referencial column as `integer` and `unsigned`

   ```
   $table->integer('debtor_id')->unsigned();
   $table->integer('creditor_id')->unsigned();
   ```
2. Set the relationship with the `foreign` `Table` method:

   ```
   $table->foreign('debtor_id')
       ->references('id')->on('user');
   $table->foreign('creditor_id')
       ->references('id')->on('user');
   ```

Comment: I could solve the problem without your suggestion. Are these best practices for set up this relations?

Comment: @Sebastian Guess so, that's the way I learnt it and no problems until now.